# explanation as to why instantiating the elements of an array of objects needs to be done inside a method

Tags: java

Java beginner here who is terribly confused as to why

1) this is **valid**:

```
public class MyArrayOfObjects {

    MyArrayOfObjects[] myArray = new MyArrayOfObjects[5];

    void InstantiateElements (){
        myArray[0] = new MyArrayOfObjects();
    }
}
```

2) while this is **not**:

```
public class MyArrayOfObjects {

    MyArrayOfObjects[] myArray = new MyArrayOfObjects[5];

    myArray[0] = new MyArrayOfObjects();

}
```

from my understanding, each element of the array of objects is instantiating a MyArrayOfObjects object. So why does option 1 work while 2 does not?

Comment: "option 2 work while 1 does not"? are you sure?

Comment: Shouldn't it be "So why does option 1 work while 2 does not?"?

Comment: you are both correct. sorry for the mixup. fixed now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Statements other than variable declarations must occur in:

- Methods
- Constructors
- Initializer blocks

In your second block of code, the statement assigning a value to the first element of the array is *not* a variable declaration, so it can't occur directly in the class.

As for why Java is designed this way - to my mind it just makes things simpler. You should put logic to be executed as part of initialization into a constructor. (I would generally try to avoid initializer blocks as well, as it's easy to forget about them when debugging.)

From [section 8.1.6 of the Java Language Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.1.6):

> A class body may contain declarations of members of the class, that is, fields (§8.3), classes (§8.5), interfaces (§8.5) and methods (§8.4). A class body may also contain instance initializers (§8.6), static initializers (§8.7), and declarations of constructors (§8.8) for the class.

Answer (score 3):

`myArray[0] = new MyArrayOfObjects();` is a statement – a line of *executable* code.
Statements can only appear in methods or initializer blocks.

Class definitions can only contain *declarations* (fields, methods, constructors, inner classes), not statements.
Fields can also have initializers.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put this line:

`myArray[0] = new MyArrayOfObjects();`

into an constructor. The class body can't contain statements, just declarations.

Comment: well, doesn't necessarily have to be in a constructor. Can also be a normal method or initializer block.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly an answer to why, this has been answered already but as an addition. You could initialize your array on declaration with an array initializer:

```
public class MyArrayOfObjects {

    MyArrayOfObjects[]  foo = new MyArrayOfObjects[] { new MyArrayOfObjects(), null, null, null, null };
}
```